# How to send axios post to socket io server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to send a POST to a socket.io server and print it on the screen. This needs to be done in real time. I will open up socket io server, leave it open on my browser, and every time I send a post to it, it needs to print the value on the screen.
I have no prior experience in Node,so I'm a little bit lost on how to do it.
This is my socket.io server (almost the exact same one from the documentation tutorial):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log("USER CONNECTED!")
      
    });
    server.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

And I'm sending a post to it from another server every time it gets a request. I'm using axios:

```
axios.post('http://myhost:3000/',qs.stringify({
     test: 'test'
   }))
   .then(res => {
     console.log(` >STATUS: ${res.status}`);
    })
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
   })
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (/var/www/html/MYFOLDER/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/var/www/html/MYFOLDER/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/www/html/ROMA/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1340:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I don't know exactly how to do what I described. Any other suggestion is accepted,not only fixes on my code.

Comment: You may have not copied into the question, but where is your POST endpoint on the express service specified? There is a GET, but not a POST.

Comment: I thought the post would go into "io.on('connection', (socket) => {...});", am i wrong? Like i said, im really not experience in Node/js, even worse with Socket.io

Comment: Socket io would be for websocket/ws connections. HTTP POST which is what you are doing with axios needs to be specified as an endpoint, similar to what you did with GET. Where are you seeing that ws would accept http post requests in general?

Comment: The server im sending the post from is a HTTP server. I thought it wat the only way to send the post. So how should i send it? Is this why im getting this error i posted?

Comment: What is your intention though? To send an HTTP POST or send a message to the web socket? They are different. If the intention is to send a post, then you need to  `app.post('/', (req, res) => { res.json({ foo: 'bar' }) });`

Comment: Well,i thought i had answered but i think i didn't. So, i will send a post like you said: app.post('/', (req, res) => { res.json({ foo: 'bar' }) }); and how do i ''receive'' it on my Socket.IO server?? Can you please answer me that. Sorry im not very good with Node...

Comment: It seems like a lot of steps are possibly missing. When you went through the tutorial on setting up the server and client on the socket .o documentation, what happened when you connected the socket io client and sent messages? Or alternatively what happened when you sent a socket message using a tool like postman or similar? At least start with the tutorial and see if you can get that working.